# Unable to see debug values in Eclipse CDT + mingw64 + cmake

Tags: cmake, eclipse-cdt, mingw-w64, msys2

I installed msys2 + mingw64 + mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb. I'm using CMake to
create the Makefiles and i'm able to debug in Eclipse Neon/Luna, setting
breakpoints, etc. but i cannot get any debug value, it fails with:

"Multiple errors reported.

1) Failed to execute MI command:"

I can debug and see values from the msys2 command line but not in eclipse (i'm sure Eclipse loads either msys2 gdb or mingw64 gdb).

Using Eclipse Luna and not picking DFS didn't make any difference, just wondering whether anyone went through this.

TIA